# Cannot access Vuex getter inside method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

The method below calls a weather API and since it needs to fetch API data before the component loads, it's placed in a **created** lifecycle hook.

```
getWeather() {
  const lat = this.$store.getters.getLatitude;
  const long = this.$store.getters.getLatitude;
  console.log('lat is ' + lat);
  let url =
    'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' +
    lat +
    '&lon=' +
    long +
    '&units=metric&APPID=' +
    process.env.VUE_APP_OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY;

  axios
    .get(url)
    .then((response) => {
      this.currentTemp = response.data.main.temp + '°C';
      this.minTemp = response.data.main.temp_min + '°C';
      this.maxTemp = response.data.main.temp_max + '°C';
      this.pressure = response.data.main.pressure + 'hPa';
      this.humidity = response.data.main.humidity + '%';
      this.wind = response.data.wind.speed + 'm/s';
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
},
  },

  created() {
    this.getWeather();
  },
```

Vuex store

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex'


Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    latitude: '',
    longitude: '',
  },
  mutations: {

  
    SET_LATITUDE(state, payload) {
      state.latitude = payload
    },
    SET_LONGITUDE(state, payload) {
      state.longitude = payload
    }

  },

  actions: {

    GET_DATA({ commit }) {
    
      var self = this
      .
      .
      .
     // LOGIC TO GET USER DATA ( LAT AND LONG FROM DATABASE )
      .
      .
      .

    self.ddb_data = [...data.Items];
                    const latitude = self.ddb_data[0].user_meta_data.coordinates.latitude
                    const longitude = self.ddb_data[0].user_meta_data.coordinates.longitude

                    commit('SET_LATITUDE', latitude)
                    commit('SET_LONGITUDE', longitude)
                  }
                });
              }
            });
          });
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return;
      }

    },

   

    },
  
  },

  getters: {

    getLatitude(state) {
      return state.latitude;
    },
    getLongitude(state) {
      return state.longitude;
    },

  },


});



export default store;
```

The issue comes in getting the lat and long from the vuex getters i.e. `$store.getters.getLatitude` and `$store.getters.getLongitude`. It seems like the getters are not returning the data when used inside the method (after page is reloaded ). The getters seem to work when used in a computed property ( regardless of page reload ).
How do I access the getters' data inside the method ?

Comment: Can you define "not working" in more detail?

Comment: it does not return the data. the getter when used for example inside a computed property, returns the expected value (e.g. 240.00). But when used inside the method, it does not return this value ( strangely when page is reloaded )

Comment: A little more detail about your vuex initialization/hydration might be useful for folks too. As a shot in the dark, have you tried calling getWeather on the [nextTick](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)?

Comment: just added the vuex store file. yes tried nextTick to no avail.

Comment: Where did you use GET_DATA()?

Comment: @KienHT that's irrelevant. I've already specified that the data is received with no issues when used in a computed property. just not in the function. and i believe this is because the vuex state is not loaded yet when the getWeather function executes.

Comment: Vuex's `$store` can be safely assimilated with `computed` properties, part of injections and reactivity. The only hook that doesn't have access to injections and reactivity is `beforeCreated`. Which means what you're describing is inaccurate. You either didn't copy/paste the function properly or you have a different error causing what you're describing. As a side note, I can't help but notice what's probably a mistake: `const long = this.$store.getters.getLatitude;`. Could you provide a *runnable* [mcve]? Use codesanbox.io if you need a multi-file node-like online editor.

Comment: The getter you mentioned works fine. Also, I didn't share the full code since it's very large and contains a lot of unnecessary AWS config data. Can't be reproduced on codesandbox for the same reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case a watch property as follows seems to solve the issue,

```
  watch: {
    latLong: {
      handler(value) {
        if (value.lat && value.long) {
          this.getWeather();
        }
      },
      immediate: true,
    },
  },
```